# Play Framework: Unable to read URLs from application.conf

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I need to configure some URLs for my Play application so I added them to `application.conf`:

```
application.url="http://www.mydomain.com"
application.url.images="http://www.anotherdomain.com"
application.url.images.logo="${application.url.images}/logo.png"
...
```

Here below is the code I use in my views to access the entries above:

```
@(title: String)
@import play.api.Play.current

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    ...

    <img src="@{ currrent.configuration.getString("application.url.images.logo") }" />

    ...
</html>
```

Well... I'm getting crazy since whenever I run the application I always get the following error message:

```
/home/j3d/Projects/test-app/conf/application.conf: 14-19: application.url.images.logo has type OBJECT rather than STRING
```

Any idea? Am I missing something? Or is it a bug?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Config in [Typesafe Configuration](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) library used in Play represents JSON-like structure. Dot notation is syntax sugar to create nested objects (`{ ... }` in JSON). For example:

```
application.url="http://example.com"
application.images.logo="http://example.com/img/1.png"
application.images.header="http://example.com/img/3.png"
```

is equivalent to following JSON:

```
{
  "application": {
    "url": "http://example.com",
    "images": {
      "logo": "http://example.com/img/1.png",
      "header": "http://example.com/img/3.png"
    }
  }
}
```

In your example you first assign string to `application.url`, then trying to add keys to it (key `url` in `application.url.images`), like it is JSON object, not string. I don't know exact behavior of Typesafe Config in this case, and why it don't raise error immediately when reading config file.

Try rearranging hierarchy of config keys, i.e.:

```
application.url.prefix="http://www.mydomain.com"
application.url.images.prefix="http://www.anotherdomain.com"
application.url.images.logo="${application.url.images}/logo.png"
```

Here `application.url` will be object with keys `prefix` and `images`, and `application.url.images` will be object with keys `prefix` and `logo`.

Comment: Thanks... It works :-) Just let me point out that ${application.url.images} must be outside the double-quotes (i.e. ${application.url.images}"/logo.png".